# How to maintain the order of sections in pyramid chart of LightningChartJS?

Tags: javascript, charts, pie-chart, lightningchart

In the pie chart when we hide a section and then unhide it, its position is maintained. The section reappears at the same location. Whereas in pyramid charts the position of the section changes it reappears at the bottom of the pyramid chart irrespective of where it was present initially.

[image: The 2015-2016 section reappears at the bottom of the pyramid in the third image.]

[image: The testing section reappears at the same location where it was present initially.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Charts can rearrange their slices by using [Slice Sorters](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.1.0/globals.html#slicesorters) to keep the order of slices consistent - however, by default the Pyramid Chart does not use a sorting method.

Using the setSliceSorter() method of the Chart should help in keeping the order of slices consistent.